# Saltstack passing character Escaping backslash and doublequotes for cronjobs Variables

Tags: cron, jinja2, salt-stack

I am writing a sls template in saltstack and tried to correctly write a cronjob entry but i am not able to do so cause compiler always cries about syntax problem cause it seems the escaping is not working as i thought.
i need the escaping backslashes inside the cron command too cause otherwise cronjob does not use the format charackters correctly.

this is the code in my template

```
{{instance}} cron-entry-for-backup-daily:
 cron.present:
   - user: root
   - name: "{{ online_basedir }}/online_tools/db-tools.py -b {{ settings.port }} -s {{ settings.online_master }} -x {{ instance + '.domain.name' }} backup -d {{ instance }} -f {{ '/opt/onlinebackupdir/' + instance + '/' + instance + '-odoo_db-' + '`date' + '\"' + '+\%Y_\%m_\%d-\%H_\%M' + '\"' + '`' + '_daily.zip'}}"
   - minute: '*'
   - hour: '22'
   - daymonth: '*'
   - month: '*'
   - dayweek: '1-6'
   - identifier: {{ instance + '_dailybackup' }}
   - comment: 'Installed via Salt'
```

the cronjob entry should look like this

```
 * 22 * * 1-6 /opt/online/online_tools/db-tools.py -b 63000 -s xyz123 -x sub.domain.name backup -d dbname -f /opt/onlinebackupdir/dbname/dbname-odoo_db-`date "+\%Y_\%m_\%d-\%H_\%M"`_daily.zip
```

If i execute this on command line it work if i execute it via cron it works ....

Error message:

> i cannot compile my code from the sls file  expected , but
>   found ''   in "", line 124, column 154:
>        ... ckupdir/dbname/dbname-odoo_db-`date"+\%Y_\%m_\%d-\%H_\%M"`_daily.zip"

i already tried some ways but i think i am unable to solve it at the moment to much brain dead already :-( maybe someone knows a solution i also checked the jinja docs for escaping aso ... but i am helpless at the moment

tries:

```
'`date +\%Y_\%m_\%d-\%H_\%M`' --> error
'`date "+\%Y_\%m_\%d-\%H_\%M"`' --> error
'`date \"+\%Y_\%m_\%d-\%H_\%M\"`' --> error
'`date '+'\%Y_\%m_\%d-\%H_\%M`' --> error 
'`date '+\%Y_\%m_\%d-\%H_\%M'`' --> error
'`date \"+"\%Y_\%m_\%d-\%H_\%M"\"'`' --> error 
'`date' + '"' + '+\%Y_\%m_\%d-\%H_\%M' + '"' + '`' --> error 
'`date' + '"' + '+\%Y_\%m_\%d-\%H_\%M' + '"' + '`' --> error 
'`date +%Y_%m_%d-%H%M`' --> compiled and worked in command line but not inside crontab % needs to be escaped
```

in the meantime i tried this too

```
"{{ online_basedir }}/online_tools/db-tools.py -b {{ settings.port }} -s {{ settings.online_master_pw }} -x {{ instance + '.domainname.net' }} backup -d {{ instance }} -f {{ '/opt/onlinebackupdir/' + instance + '/' + instance + '-odoo_db-' }} + {% raw %} `date "+\%Y_\%m_\%d-\%H_\%M"` {% endraw %} + {{'_daily.zip'}}"
"{{ online_basedir }}/online_tools/db-tools.py -b {{ settings.port }} -s {{ settings.online_master_pw }} -x {{ instance + '.domainname.net' }} backup -d {{ instance }} -f {{ '/opt/onlinebackupdir/' + instance + '/' + instance + '-odoo_db-' + {% raw %} `date "+\%Y_\%m_\%d-\%H_\%M"` {% endraw %} + '_daily.zip'}}"
```

This does not work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i solved the Problem with this solution, maybe this is not the best way but it solves my problem....
If someone reads this i would be interested in why `{% raw %} .... {% endraw % }`
does not work

SOLUTION:

```
"{{ online_basedir }}/online_tools/db-tools.py -b {{ settings.port }} -s {{ settings.online_master_pw }} -x {{ instance + '.domainname.net' }} backup -d {{ instance }} -f {{ '/opt/onlinebackupdir/' + instance + '/'  + instance + '-odoo_db-' + '`date \\\"+\\\\%Y_\\\\%m_\\\\%d-\\\\%H_\\\\%M\\\"`' + '_weekly.zip'}}"
```

now the line in the crontab looks exactly like i need it:

```
.......`date "+\%Y_\%m_\%d-\%H_\%M"`..... .zip
```

RESULT in my BACKUP Folder: `instance-odoo_db-2016_10_19-22_00_daily.zip`

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use string concatenation inside the template context. All that does is add another layer of quoting you have to escape. Likewise, we can use a form for the YAML string that doesn't need any escaping and makes it easier to read:

```yaml
{{instance}} cron-entry-for-backup-daily:
 cron.present:
   - user: root
   - name: >-
       {{ online_basedir }}/online_tools/db-tools.py
       -b {{ settings.port }}
       -s {{ settings.online_master }}
       -x {{ instance }}.domain.name backup
       -d {{ instance }}
       -f /opt/onlinebackupdir/{{ instance }}/{{ instance }}-odoo_db-`date "+\%Y_\%m_\%d-\%H_\%M"`_daily.zip
   - hour: '22'
   - dayweek: '1-6'
   - identifier: {{ instance }}_dailybackup
   - comment: Installed via Salt
```